# Fetch field value from another one in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I am just about the implement my custom belongs to component that has a dynamic functionality, on the fly it needs to make a HTTP call to the server and pass it few values, I need to pass it a value from another BelongsTo dropdown. How can this be achieved in Laravel Nova? Of course i can see which element has this value, but was wondered if there is a smarter way.

Comment: Can you please provide some code for more understanding